# How to prevent \footnotetext from inserting vertical space where it is invoked?

Tags: spacing, footnotes, vertical-spacing

I've noticed that `\footnotetext` is inserting unwanted vertical space according to rules I do not understand. Sometimes I can fix this by moving `\footnotetext` closer to `\footnotemark`, but in some cases this would make the source less readable and would give no advantage over using plain `\footnote`. Here is an example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

An important\footnotemark{} result:
\[
  2 + 2 = 4.
\]
%% Comment/uncomment next line:
\footnotetext{Nice to know.}

\hrule

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to use `\footnotetext` anywhere without the risk of getting unwanted vertical space? If so, how? If not, what are the rules?

Comment: "Is it possible to use \footnotetext anywhere without the risk of getting unwanted vertical space?" No.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, do you know what is the point of this vertical space? What are the rules?

Comment: a footnote text makes a node (it has to so it tracks the final page) TeX is TeX and it's virtually impossible to make a node without adversely affecting space somewhere you see the same with `\color` which tries hard (but fails) not to affect spacing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, and what about `\footnote`? Can it insert unwanted space?

Comment: `\footnote` makes a mark so is almost always used in hmode which is a much safer place, if you always use \footnotetext in hmode things are much easier

Comment: If you must put `\footnotetext` in a line by itself, use `\vapace{-\baselineskip}` to hide it.

Answer (score 3):

a footnote text makes a node (it has to so it tracks the final page) TeX is TeX and it's virtually impossible to make a node without adversely affecting space somewhere you see the same with `\color` which tries hard (but fails) not to affect spacing.

In this case, a tex primitive `\hrule` following a display does not trigger `\baselineskip`, it is added directly to the main vertical list.

```
...\hbox(6.44444+0.83333)x43.33319, shifted 150.8334, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
...\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
```

But an `\insert` node (used by `\footnotetext` to migrate the text to the footnote area) does trigger `\baselineskip` (and leaves an empty white paragraph box)

```
...\hbox(6.44444+0.83333)x43.33319, shifted 150.8334, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 6.0 plus 3.0 minus 3.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 11.16667
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 345.0fil []
...\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
```

In general avoid adding such nodes in vertical mode. It is much easier to avoid adverse effects in hmode.